# add style's to the textarea 's specific line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, textarea

I have html textarea dynamically it's content changing line by line. I want to add some styles to the updated or modified line content. Is there any windows selection, like properties, to do it??

What I want is make user feel, that the change has **happen**.  Or any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Make the user feel that *what* change has happened? In *what way*, and in response to *what*, do you want the lines to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to achieve it just by CSS with textarea, but the problem is solvable for sure :)

- you can replace textarea with `<div contenteditable><p></p></div>`
- you can set textarea CSS: `background: transparent` and manipulate some element below the textarea
- you can modify this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/cotenoni/jquery-linedtextarea to manipulate specific lines (some CSS work required, cause by default you can manipulate just left column)
- you can set custom background for textarea and move it up and down to specific line by `background-position: 0 X`