# Applying CSS to only certain lines in textarea

Tags: javascript

I have a `textarea` that needs green color for the line that begins with double slash(//).

```
<textarea id="code-init" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

now I have used following code to attempt what I thought,

```
document.getElementById("code-init").onkeyup = e => {

if(e.key === '/') {
    console.log(e.key)
    document.getElementById("code-init").onkeyup = e =>{
        if(e.key === '/')
            e.target.style.color = "green"
        document.getElementById("code-init").onkeyup = e =>{
            if(e.key === "Enter")
                e.target.style.color = "white"
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Examining highlighting systems will show you that they create markup in order to highlight sections. You don't specifically need a `<textarea>` to get key events but simulating one can be hard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954726/add-styles-to-the-textarea-s-specific-line

Answer (score 0):

You could simulate an div and insert each letter as span. Callback and check if they include `//` then traverse the characters to define "a line" and color the spans of the "line"? http://jsbin.com/qinacusuzo/edit?html,output

Or use linear gradient to color the background of the textarea: https://jsfiddle.net/c6hzg08d/

A hard task, maybe worth looking for libraries that help you achieve this.